# Node.js client-sessions - Large unguessable string?

Tags: node.js, security, cookies

I have a Node.js webserver and to securely store a session cookie on the client I am using [client-sessions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/client-sessions).

To setup a cookie one can set some properties like the cookieName and a secret which "should be a large unguessable string".
But how should this string be and how do I create such a string and furthermore how do I correctly use it in the program? Use environment variables or read it from a file?

Using a random string at startup isn't very smart in my eyes because if the webserver crashes then it creates a new secret and can't read all previously issued cookies am I right?

```
app.use(sessions({
  cookieName: 'mySession', // cookie name dictates the key name added to the request object
  secret: 'blargadeeblargblarg', // should be a large unguessable string
  duration: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, // how long the session will stay valid in ms
  activeDuration: 1000 * 60 * 5 // if expiresIn < activeDuration, the session will be extended by activeDuration milliseconds
}));
```

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv

Comment: Thank you for suggesting that package I will definitly use it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would generate a UUID or use a password manager program to generate a large random string. Then store that in system environment variables so that it isn't committed in your code.